# Is there a way to filter directory to primary storage when picking a file from intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I am saving my pdf files in Documents Folder or Download Folder. I want to access the file via the primary storage as when I choose the file in the "Downloads" or "Documents", the uri is changed and the file name gets changed to something like msf:63 or document:63

[here is the image of when choosing the file in which directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mBfi.png)

so my problem is I want to get rid of the "Documents" and the "Downloads" so the user will not choose the file from there. Is that possible?

Here is the code when I try to open the file

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).also {
                val mime = arrayOf("application/pdf", //pdf
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") //docx

                it.type = "application/*"
                it.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mime)
                activityLauncher.launch(it){ its ->
                    if (its.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        val str = its.data!!.data!!.path!!.split("/").toTypedArray()
                        whichNoFileSelected(tag)!!.text = str[str.size - 1]
                        whichNoFileSelected(tag)!!.textSize = 11f
                        if(str[str.size - 1].contains(".docx")){
                            whichNoFileSelected(tag)!!.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                                    requireContext().resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_doc, null),
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null
                            )
                        }else{
                            whichNoFileSelected(tag)!!.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                                    requireContext().resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pdf, null),
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null
                            )
                        }

                        uploadImage(its.data!!, "document")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `the file name gets changed to something like msf:63 or document:63` That is not a file name but part of your uri. But what does it matter? If you need the file name you can query() this uri for it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get rid of the "Documents" and the "Downloads" so the user will not choose the file from there. Is that possible?

No.

Also, please get rid of this line and the code that depends on it:

```kotlin
val str = its.data!!.data!!.path!!.split("/").toTypedArray()
```

Use `getType()` on a `ContentResolver` to find the MIME type associated with the content that the user chose. Not only will this handle the `Documents` and `Downloads` trees, but it will handle all the other `Uri` scenarios as well (e.g., user chooses a document from Google Drive).